# Is 'Arel::Nodes::Quoted' the best way to avoid injection when using 'NamedFunctions'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, arel

I was developing a specific filter when I ran into the following question:

```ruby
input_from_user = Arel::Nodes::Quoted.new(input_from_user.split('.').second)
separator = Arel::Nodes::Quoted.new('.')

Model.where(Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('split_part', [input_from_user, separator, 2]).eq('random_value'))
```

This works, but I am not sure if this is really secure, I know that 'Arel.sql' or 'Literal' would not garantee any security, 'Quoted' node seems to handle injection, but I am not 100% into injection security, is there any other way to write this? (which does not involves creating fields on the database) if not, is this safe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**:

Yes these will be escaped accordingly, just as they would be for higher level AR query methods.

**Explanation**:

So here is how `Nodes::NamedFunction` will work in SQL compilation (in a nut shell):

1. visit the `Nodes::NamedFunction` ([Source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/activerecord/lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb#L384))
2. Visit each expression (your Array argument) ([Source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/893e5e25e5d83416c8f270dd1b1e32d9e5da76f5/activerecord/lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb#L824))
3. Since they are `Nodes::Quoted` visit those expressions ([Source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/activerecord/lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb#L84))
4. Use `quote` method ([Source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/activerecord/lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb#L794))
5. Use Postgres Adapter `quote` method ([Source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/quoting.rb#L19))
6. Use Abstract Adapter`quote` method because these are `String`s ([Source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/quoting.rb#L11))
7. Use Postgres Adapter `quote_string` to escape strings ([Source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/7fe221d898afe877f282b549bd8bb908ebe1843d/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/quoting.rb#L45))
8. Use Postgres connection `escape` method (from the `pg` gem) ([Source](https://github.com/ged/ruby-pg/blob/9929ac9f3fee17c9f2d9930728a0a303d90a9ac9/ext/pg_connection.c#L1604) or  [Docs](https://deveiate.org/code/pg/PG/Connection.html#method-i-escape) because they are easier to read)

The result will be  `split_part('input_from_user','.',2)`.

**Additional Notes**:

1. Your only other issue is that your `where` does not have an queryable expression (no predication) of any kind so you would need to modify this to something like the following (which will generate an `Arel::Nodes::Equality` object)

```
Model.where(
  Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new(
    'split_part', 
    [input_from_user, separator, 2]
  ).eq('sub string'))
```

2. `Arel::Nodes` provides a convenience method ([`build_quoted`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/f95c0b7e96eb36bc3efc0c5beffbb9e84ea664e4/activerecord/lib/arel/nodes/casted.rb#L48)) that reads a little nicer. e.g.

```
input_from_user = Arel::Nodes.build_quoted(input_from_user.split('.').second)
separator = Arel::Nodes.build_quoted('.')

Model.where(
  Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new(
    'split_part', 
    [input_from_user, separator, 2]
  ).eq('sub string'))
```

Comment: I forgot to add the '.eq' as predicate, but that was it, nice answer, thanks a lot!!